# How can I fetch a CSV file locally in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use fetch to read a CSV local file, but it says Network file request failed. I'm using React Native 48.0 with expo.

Here's the code showing what I'm doing:

This part just reads the csv

```
const parseCSV = (text) => {
  const result = {
    header: [],
    data: [],
  };

  const [header, ...content] = text.split('\n')

  result.header = header.split(';')

  content.forEach((item) => {
    result.data.push(item.split(';'))
  })

  console.log(result)

  return result;

}
```

This part is that I'm having the problem:

```
const DBTeste = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('../public/teste.csv')
    .then((r) => r.text())
    .then((text) => {
      parseCSV(text);
    });
  }, []);

  return
  
};

export default DBTeste;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not fetch files with Fetch API same as on the web as there's no concept of URL on mobile. Can you try to convert your CSV file to JSON and then import it manually - https://csvjson.com/csv2json